# How to export excel some specific columns from json object in angular

Tags: angular, excel, export-to-excel, angular-datatables

I have an array of objects in JSON format. And I am following this link [link here](https://www.thecodehubs.com/generate-and-download-excel-file-in-angular-7/) to export an Excel file and its working properly. By default, Excel file uses object keys as headers and export all objects data, But I want to export some specific columns data from JSON object array in download excel file. If Is this possible? please suggest a better solution.

exportexcel.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

const EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
const EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';

@Injectable()
export class ExcelService {

  constructor() { }

  public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
  }
  private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
     const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {type: EXCEL_TYPE});
     FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + '_Exportfile'+ EXCEL_EXTENSION); 
  }
}
```

Used in the component.ts

```
DownloadExcelfile():void {
     this.excelService.exportAsExcelFile(this.myjsonarray, 'Downloadexcel');
 }
```

Used in the component.html

```
<button (click)="DownloadExcelfile()" class="btn-primary" type="submit" >DownloadExcel</button>
```

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Kindly show the code you have done so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi@Ismail I added my code please check and suggest a solution.